# What math is used in the theory of quantum computing?

Tags: soft-question, physics

I'd like to know what rung of the math ladder one need be on to grasp how a quantum computer computes.

I realize this might not be a simple answer, so I'm just looking for an idea of the broad topics required.

Thanks.

Comment: Linear algebra gets used a lot in quantum computing.

Comment: [Fourier analysis on groups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58515/what-is-fourier-analysis-on-groups-and-does-it-have-applications-to-physics/58595#58595).

Comment: To all that are interested in Quantum Information: The [Quantum Information and Foundations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36039/quantum-information-and-foundations?referrer=G-oXDJgd8JaWXYyF_kRbzQ2) proposal is currently in commitment phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the foundation you need to understand linear algebra, projective geometry and how to build circuits out of AND, OR, NOT gates. For the algorithms themselves, you need to know a little about rational approximations and the Fourier transformation. You can start to learn about Quantum Computing from [here](http://michaelnielsen.org/blog/quantum-computing-for-the-determined/) but I also recommend working through the book he wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Since all quantum algorithms I know, deal with finite dimensional system, knowledge of unitary groups $\text{U}(N)$ is important, because it governs the evolution of the finite quantum system without relaxation. For the [QA to approximate the Jones Polynomial](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0511096), it doesn't hurt to know something about knot theory.