# Why do we replace 's' with '$j\omega$'

Tags: laplace-transform

The problem arises from frequency response method (control systems ) and most books try to explain why we replace $'s'$ by $'j\omega'$ in frequency response. So, let me get to the math part; Our system is$$ y(t)=ae^{-j\omega t} +be^{j\omega t}$$
Which is the steady state response.

The input is sinusoid $x(t)=A\sin(wt)$; and thus the output is also a sinusoid. In the Laplace domain, the relation between input($x(s)$) and output ($y(s)$) is $$y(s)=G(s)x(s)$$ where $G(s)$ is the transfer function.now here is my problem, when finding $a$ and $b$ here is what they did.
$$a=G(s)\frac{(\omega A)}{(s^{2}+\omega^{2})}(s+j\omega)$$ and
$$b=G(s)\frac{(\omega A)}{(s^{2}+\omega^{2})}(s-j\omega)$$
( I know how this is derived but I don't know the next step which is:-)

When evaluating a and b at $-j\omega$ and $j\omega$ respectively we get;
$$a=-A\frac{G(-j\omega)}{2j}$$
$$b=A\frac{G(j\omega)}{2j}$$
So, my question is why did we pick the point $j\omega$ in place of $'s'$ For $b$ and $-j\omega$ For $a$?

$TRIAL$

May be initial conditions....

Comment: Because frequency response is closely related to Fourier transform and in most cases, the Fourier transform and Laplace transform are related by $s=j\omega$

Comment: And if you are asking why don't we use Fourier transform in the first place, the answer is Laplace transform has simpler form and less complexities

Comment: But the paradigm "replace $s$ by $j\omega$" hides many pitfalls, and should no longer be presented to students!  A first visible inadequacy is that the domain of integration is not the same ($(0,\infty)$ for Laplace, and ($(-\infty,\infty)$ for Fourier ). Fundamentaly Laplace Transforms deals with **causal** functions (http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/jav/soton/HELM/workbooks/workbook_20/20_1_causal_fns.pdf), whereas there is nothing similar for Fourier transforms.

Comment: @JeanMarie You are right. I have discussed the situation in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987998)

Comment: @polfosol ... and [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1710280) for me :)