# When does the Fourier algebra coincide with the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra?

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

For a given locally compact group $G$ the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra $B(G)$ is defined as  the algebra of matrix coefficients of unitary representations $\pi:G\to B(H)$. Similarly, the Fourier algebra $A(G)$ is defined as the algebra of matrix coefficients of the left regular representation $\lambda:G\to B(L_2(G))$ (see [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Fourier-algebra(2)) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56077/reference-request-fourier-and-fourier-stieltjes-algebras)). P.Eymard in his [original paper](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMF_1964__92__181_0) ((3.6), $1^\circ$) says that when $G$ is compact, these algebras coincide:
$$
A(G)=B(G).
$$ 
Is this the only case when they coincide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Any function in $A(G)$ vanishes at infinity, whereas $B(G)$ contains the constant functions. So whenever $G$ is non-compact, $A(G)\subsetneq B(G)$.

A related question is when $A(G) = B(G)\cap C_0(G)$. See e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.5400.

Comment: Thank you! But Yemon Choi has already answered this question in MathOverflow http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181703/when-is-the-fourier-algebra-ag-enough-close-to-the-fourier-stieltjes-algebra